# How to override the back button's default action?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to check all text fields have been set (.text != "") before the navigation bar's back button pops the view controller when it is clicked.

How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply replace the back button with your own `UIBarButtonItem`. This way you can use a custom action to check all input fields, or at least disable the button as long as your checks are not passed. Finally call `popViewControllerAnimated:` on your navigation controller.